# Generics: Cannot convert from Collections.emptyList() to List<String>

Tags: java, generics, collections, empty-list

Why

```
public List<String> getList(){
    if (isMyListOKReady())
        return myList;
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

compiles well, but for

```
public List<String> getList(){
    return isMyListReady() ? myList : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Eclipse says `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>"`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to take care of *type safety* of empty list.

So return the empty list of string like this

```
public List<String> getList(){
    return isMyListReady() ? myList : Collections.<String>emptyList();
}
```

To be more specific, look you function is returning `List<String>`. So when you are using ternary operator then your condition should also return `List<String>`.

But in the case of `Collections.emptyList()` doesn't have it's type as `List<String>`. So Just need to specify the type of empty collection. So just use `Collections.<String>emptyList()`.

Comment: "need to take care of type safety" is kind of vague - what's happening is the compiler is failing to infer the correct type argument within the ternary expression, so you need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the type mismatch is quite obscure and hidden in the logics of conditional expressions. In short, Java will try to determine the result type of the expression by looking at the types of the second and third operand, **which may lead to a hidden cast** or binary promotion in case of primitives! You can make it clearer, if you extract every variable into a local one with the original type and then look at your condition again.

I don't want to extract the chapter, but it is well explained in [Java Puzzlers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X), chapter 8 Dos Equis. Get a copy of it if you can, it's really worth it.